# PHP + cURL - output is older than expected?

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to figure out for two days now why this isn't working. Basically I'm playing around with TradeMe's API and they have a .json file here:

Link 1: http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/Latest.json

Rather than exhaust the API rate limit I thought ok... I'll just write a script for my web server that grabs this file and returns it to me (I'll have to cache it locally of course but I haven't quite gotten there yet). Let's just say my fetcher URL is this:

Link 2: http://{MY URL}/trademe/fetcher.php?url=http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/Latest.json

The thing is... what cURL returns me for link 2 is NOT what link 1 returns me! Every time I run my script (link 2) it always gives me an older version of link 1's JSON file (I know it's an older version because I look at the ListingId numbers in the JSON file). Sometimes I run link 2 and it gives me a newer JSON and then when I refresh the script it gives me the older JSON again! (Note that if I access link 1 directly in Chrome it always gives me the latest JSON file. There is something wrong with my script?)

Here's my script:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(3600);

header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Expires: on, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $contents;
?>
```

I'm basically invoking this script through jQuery's $.getJSON. I've even put the no cache headers in my index.php and also put in $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); but no luck.

Any ideas?

(This may shed some light but I've yet to find anything: http://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/)

Cheers

Comment: I think you are likely misinterpreting the information returned to you. They have "Caching" section in API docs, it says all requests get cached responses within some time after the call.

Comment: Interesting, but notice how when I access the API directly via link 1 (as opposed to using my script) the updates are much more frequent? Like, how can I replicate that with the script... if possible?

Comment: This is an API. They are OK with the fact that you will send requests via some script. Do you really think they made an extra layer of protection against something they allow just to return a bit older results. I'm sorry, that doesn't make much sense. My bet is the problem does not exist. You could ask them, since I see no flaws with your script, maybe they can comment on that.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah, it'll be worth contacting them about it. Cheers.

Comment: Please, when they answer, post the solution as an answer and accept it so the question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to one of the guys at TradeMe and while I don't think we really figured out why link 1 and link 2 acted differently, a solution is to just append some random number (or even the time) to the URL, so e.g.:

http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/Latest.json&t=RANDOM_NUMBER

And then have that in the fetching script or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

At least my version of Chrome sends max-age cache directive by default, I think this is the difference between the requests. Try to add this before `curl_exec`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0'
));
```

Comment: Just now I tried it and it didn't work for me. Thanks though (perhaps it may work for others?)! I did find a workaround earlier however (my answer below this comment).